# Using ColdFusion to consume a webservice

Tags: web-services, coldfusion

Per recommendations below I now only have the following:

```
<cfscript> 
ws = CreateObject("webservice","http://demo2.mvrs.com/StiConnect/StiConnectWebService.svc?wsdl"); 
</cfscript>
<cfdump var="#ws#">
```

And the java error is back:

```
You've Thrown an Application Error

java.util.NoSuchElementException

Application

Caught an exception, type = Application

The contents of the tag stack are:

array
1   
struct
COLUMN  0
ID  CF_CFPAGE
LINE    3
RAW_TRACE   at cfstTest2ecfm154367281.runPage(D:\Webs\dev\Criminal\Intranet\Web\dev\stTest.cfm:3)
TEMPLATE    D:\Webs\dev\Criminal\Intranet\Web\dev\stTest.cfm
TYPE    CFML
```

Below is the follow "Robust" error reporting from the page.

```
The web site you are accessing has experienced an unexpected error.
Please contact the website administrator. 

The following information is meant for the website developer for debugging purposes.
Error Occurred While Processing Request
Invalid construct: Either argument or name is missing.

When using named parameters to a function, each parameter must have a name.
The CFML compiler was processing:

An expression beginning with ws.OrderInteractive, on line 6, column 14.This message is usually caused by a problem in the expressions structure.
A script statement beginning with xlatstring on line 6, column 1.
A cfscript tag beginning on line 3, column 2.
A cfscript tag beginning on line 3, column 2.

The error occurred in /Intranet/Web/dev/stTest.cfm: line 6
4 : ws = CreateObject("webservice",  
5 : "http://demo2.mvrs.com/StiConnect/StiConnectWebService.svc?singleWsdl"); 
6 : xlatstring = ws.OrderInteractive(MVRMODE="MVRUSA", PROCESS="NEWREQ", Cuser="01", Cpass="Abcd.1234", Ccode"K1433", CustomOutPutType="06", OrderState="OH", DPPACode="09", Clicense1="RR653845", cSocial1="286760936", CPOLICY1="TEST_CDLIS"); 
7 : writeoutput(xlatstring); 
8 : </cfscript>
Resources:
Check the ColdFusion documentation to verify that you are using the correct syntax.
Search the Knowledge Base to find a solution to your problem.
Browser     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.97 Safari/537.36
Remote Address      172.16.0.224
Referrer    
Date/Time   29-Jan-16 01:20 PM
Stack Trace


coldfusion.compiler.CFMLParserBase$MissingNameException: Invalid construct: Either argument or name is missing.
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.FunctionParameters(cfml40.java:6265)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.ComplexReference(cfml40.java:6142)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.VariableReference(cfml40.java:6061)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.PrimaryExpression(cfml40.java:5866)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.UnaryExpression(cfml40.java:5716)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.ExponentialExpression(cfml40.java:5673)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.MultiplyDivisionExpression(cfml40.java:5626)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.IntegerDivisionExpression(cfml40.java:5607)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.ModExpression(cfml40.java:5588)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.AdditionExpression(cfml40.java:5541)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.ConcatExpression(cfml40.java:5522)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.ComparisonExpression(cfml40.java:5375)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.NotExpression(cfml40.java:5325)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.AndExpression(cfml40.java:5297)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.OrExpression(cfml40.java:5278)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.XorExpression(cfml40.java:5259)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.EqvExpression(cfml40.java:5240)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.ImpExpression(cfml40.java:5221)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.HookExpression(cfml40.java:5176)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.expr(cfml40.java:5160)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.cfScriptExpression(cfml40.java:2446)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.SimpleStatement(cfml40.java:612)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.cfscriptStatement(cfml40.java:1542)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.cfscript(cfml40.java:1404)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.cfml(cfml40.java:4342)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.cftry(cfml40.java:1147)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.cfml(cfml40.java:4336)
    at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.start(cfml40.java:4768)
    at coldfusion.compiler.NeoTranslator.parsePage(NeoTranslator.java:694)
    at coldfusion.compiler.NeoTranslator.parsePage(NeoTranslator.java:675)
    at coldfusion.compiler.NeoTranslator.parseAndTransform(NeoTranslator.java:428)
    at coldfusion.compiler.NeoTranslator.translateJava(NeoTranslator.java:370)
    at coldfusion.compiler.NeoTranslator.translateJava(NeoTranslator.java:147)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateClassLoader$TemplateCache$1.fetch(TemplateClassLoader.java:436)
    at coldfusion.util.LruCache.get(LruCache.java:180)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateClassLoader$TemplateCache.fetchSerial(TemplateClassLoader.java:362)
    at coldfusion.util.AbstractCache.fetch(AbstractCache.java:58)
    at coldfusion.util.SoftCache.get_statsOff(SoftCache.java:133)
    at coldfusion.util.SoftCache.get(SoftCache.java:81)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateClassLoader.findClass(TemplateClassLoader.java:609)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:83)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:201)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
```

I have also updated the way I am consuming the webservice using the createobject now (below you can see the way I original tried):

```
<cfscript> 
ws = CreateObject("webservice",  
"http://demo2.mvrs.com/StiConnect/StiConnectWebService.svc?singleWsdl"); 
xlatstring = ws.OrderInteractive(MVRMODE="MVRUSA", PROCESS="NEWREQ", Cuser="01", Cpass="xxx.xxx", Ccode"xxxx", CustomOutPutType="06", OrderState="OH", DPPACode="xx", Clicense1="xxxxxx", cSocial1="xxxxxxxxxx", CPOLICY1="TEST_CDLIS"); 
writeoutput(xlatstring); 
</cfscript>
```

**Below was the old way i was trying to connect and got my first error.**

```
<cftry> 


<cfinvoke  
webservice="http://demo2.mvrs.com/StiConnect/StiConnectWebService.svc?singleWsdl" 
method="OrderInteractive" 
returnvariable="OrderInteractiveResponse"> 


<cfinvokeargument name="MVRMODE" value="xxxxx"/> 
<cfinvokeargument name="Cuser" value="xxx"/> 
<cfinvokeargument name="Cpass" value="xxxx"/> 
<cfinvokeargument name="CustomOutPutType" value="6"/> 
<cfinvokeargument name="OrderState" value="GA"/> 
<cfinvokeargument name="DPPACode" value="xx"/> 
<cfinvokeargument name="Clicense1" value="201099999"/> 

</cfinvoke> 
<cfoutput>This is the reported data #OrderInteractiveResponse#</cfoutput>

<cfcatch type="application"> 
       <h3>You've Thrown an Application <b>Error</b></h3> 
        <cfoutput> 
            <!--- The diagnostic message from ColdFusion. ---> 
            <p>#cfcatch.message#</p> 
            <p>Caught an exception, type = #CFCATCH.TYPE#</p> 
            <p>The contents of the tag stack are:</p> 
            <cfdump var="#cfcatch.tagcontext#"> 
        </cfoutput> 
    </cfcatch> 
    ... 
    <cfcatch type="Any"> 
        <!--- Add exception processing code appropriate for all other  
    exceptions here ... ---> 
    </cfcatch> 
</cftry>
```

You should be able to look at the wsdl file and see all of the methods. Not sure what to try next. Any ideas what this error could mean?

Comment: What I would try next would be to create an object of that webservice and dump the variable.  That would tell you whether the problem is with the attempt to create the object, or the attempt to run the method.

Comment: Also, can you please post the complete error message?

Comment: I have added the full error report now that I am trying to createobject()

Comment: A) Dump the web service object *before* invoking the method. B) Do not use named arguments when invoking a method on the webservice. ie Just pass in the values, ie `xlatstring = ws.OrderInteractive("MVRUSA", "NEWREQ",....)`

Comment: @Leigh thank you for the recommendation. I have updated my post with what I found when I tried to dump the ws createobject. As for the parameters if I have to pass 10+ how would I know the order?

Comment: Is this a service on your site or an external one? When I try and call it, it throws a "Could not locate any port specified in the service element of the WSDL". *how would I know the order* From the WSDL if it is an external service.  The arguments data types and order are viewable when you dump the object `ws`, just look for the OrderInteractive method.